# OpenCV 2.4.9 with java on eclipse Juno - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, opencv, ubuntu

I saw many questions like this one but I couldn't get any answer..
I installed opencv2.4.9 as in this tutorial: http://www.samontab.com/web/2014/06/installing-opencv-2-4-9-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/#comment-35200 and everything went OK. When I tried running my Java project in Eclipse I run into this error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java249 in java.library.path

I saw in another answer that I need to set opencv in the user libraries but I don't have a "opencv/build/java" folder and I already try to set it to the path where the .jar file is in it.
I have no idea what to do..
Any thought?

Comment: what is the tree structure of your openCV looking like? Check your `Native library location` configuration.

Comment: What do you mean by "Native library location" configuration? Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `Native library location` configuration:

- Goto Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences:

  make sure path is like:
  `/opencv-2.4.9/build/java/x64`
  [image]

Comment: Yeah, that was part of the problem! Thanks!
The more important part wast that I was running eclipse Juno which is incompatible with Java 8. Needed to download the new Eclipse and then it worked.